# iOS Core-Data Relationship one-to-many vs. fetchedResultsController speed

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm using Core-Data to store messages from contacts

I have created a "Contact" table and a "Messages" table.

- Every message has a one-to-one relationship with a Contact
- Every contact has a one-to-many relationship with every contact's message

Right now, for showing messages, I use a simple fetchedResultsController with the contact as the predicate.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"contact = %@", self.contact];
```

Once the number of messages is starting to be consequent, the loading takes some time, since I can't index the message from their relationship.

I know that I can access to all contacts messages from the relationship, but I also need something similar to

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
```

In order to update the view as soon as there is a new message to show...

I guess my questions are :

1. Accessing to the messages from the contacts one-to-many relationship will it be faster than a **fetchedResultsController** when number of messages is consequent ?
2. Can I Order the messages from the latest to the oldest with this ?
3. Can I track any change from the contact's messages without having a fetchedResultController ? (messages can be changed/added/deleted)
4. **OR** is there just a way to indexes the messages table with the relationship ?

For the **3.** I know that I can listen to any NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification, but the thing is I don't care if another contact's sends a message while I'm on another one... I haven't find a smart way to use KVO for this model.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is likely to keep the FRC and to just configure the fetch request to batch appropriately. Arguably you don't need all old messages on the device all the time and you can delete when they get to a certain age and then query from the server if the user needs them.

For the ordering, you need to add an attribute to the entity and set it (if you don't already have one) and then set the sort descriptor on your fetch request.

Comment: So what you say, is instead of using relationship, I should put an attribute on messages table with contact's id indexed, and fetch the message with the id ?

Comment: For ordering I already have a date attribute, it is ordering when using FRC, but not when accessing messages from the contact's relationship

Comment: If you need an ordered relationship you can use one, but you need to manage the order. If you already have a date then you can get the relationship contents and then create a sorted array from that set. The FRC is still best for batch management and you should aim to limit message count anyway.

Comment: I'm already using `[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];` with a "load more message" on the top of UITableView that will increase the FetchBatchSize... But the thing is when there is like 500 messages, at one point the Fetching will be very long... (like 2-3 sec.)

Comment: You never increase the batch size, just scroll the table and it will request more data from the FRC (which will load the next batch as required)...

Comment: Huh ? really ? any example of this ? it could be really helpful

Comment: Example of what exactly? The table delegate methods use the FRC, yhe FRC deals with collecting the data and providing it. You shouldn't be using the list of fetched objects from the FRC directly.

Comment: In the `CellForRowAtIndexPath` , I'm using `[[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]` isn't that how it should be used ?